# Unknown column 'num' in field list

Tags: sql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29fb5c/1

```
CREATE TABLE People(
   id INT,
   num VARCHAR(30),
   date DATE
);

INSERT INTO People VALUES (123, "500", NOW());

SELECT num FROM people;
```

I'm getting the error "Unknown column 'num' in field list" or whenever I try using any of the columns. Am I missing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Do you have multiple tables with the same name (under different schema)? dbo.people vs me.people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a whitespace, you need to remove it.

Example of a valid and working will be:

```
CREATE TABLE People(
   id INT, num VARCHAR(30), date DATE
);
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I didn't know white space could be an issue.

Comment: @Jon it's not normally

Comment: @Phil . . . To be specific, a non-space/non-tab/non-EOL character *looked* like white space and was causing a problem.  This SQL Fiddle looks exactly the same, but it works because that character is now a real space:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac28f/1